# SwiftUI register for push notifications didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called

Tags: swiftui, push-notification, appdelegate

I am trying to subscribe to pushes, and receive device token in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to send it to the server. I have a SwiftUI App which has a `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` and it seems to work fine - `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called normally. But neither `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` gets called. There is a message in logs "Registered for push notifications with token: <...>", which probably means registration itself succeeds. Push notifications capability is added, certificates are in place, I am testing on device, not sim, but AppDelegate's methods for pushes are just not called.

I am using xcode Version 13.2.1 and ios 15.2.

Here is how I subscribe to pushes:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, _) in
      NSLog("PUSH NOTIFICATION PERMISSION GRANTED: \(granted)")
      guard granted else { return }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      }
}
```

Here are my method signatures (I know it can stop working if apple changes them a bit):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) { }
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) { }
```

EDIT!!! My apologies, I found out the problem is AzureNotificationHubs-iOS pod being in project. I don't use it for now, but the very fact that it is there, breaks delegate method calls. Does anybody maybe know how to restore the delegate calls while still keeping the azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AzureNotificationHubs-iOS uses swizzling that is why standard delegate methods don't get called. Microsoft documentation says to "Add the NHAppDelegateForwarderEnabled key [to plist] and set the value to 0" and it works. With this key in place swizzling is not used and delegate methods work as expected.

Comment: What is "swizzling" and why is it necessary? I'm just looking to get the device id/token so I can uniquely identify the device and possibly send device specific notifications. I have NotificationHubs working for tests, but want to set up server tables to support user/device specific notifications.